# How to show toast status when phone got missed call that just happened?

Tags: android

I tried to figure out CallLog and event that just happening on phone, when it got phone call or missed call.

Is it possible when I run my app and there's missed call, my app will show toast status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question on anddev

http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/miss-call-alert-in-android-t3959.html

edit: as requested in comments

```
import java.text.DateFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallLogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] strFields = {
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE
        };
        String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

        Cursor mCallCursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                strFields, null, null, strOrder);

        if (mCallCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                boolean missed = mCallCursor.getInt(mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;

                if (missed) {

                    String name = mCallCursor.getString(mCallCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));

                    String number = mCallCursor.getString(mCallCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

                    String time = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG)
                            .format(mCallCursor.getLong(mCallCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));

                    Log.d("PhoneLog", "You have a missed call from " + name + " on " + number
                            + " at " + time);
                }

            } while (mCallCursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }
}
```

make sure you have the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thanks..is it possible to show phone number who missed call the phone?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html
shows NUMBER so I'd say yes

Comment: umm...i still don't understand how to use it.. My app have a listener to check if there's misscall from 1 phone number..it will show toast or log "you have missed call from number xxxx". Could you tell me, please? Thanks

Comment: Here have a tutorial :D http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/25-android-tutorial-call-logs

Comment: Thanks :D but how to test it with log? :-/

Comment: I want to test that tutorial, but how to added Log.d(TAG, "You've got a missed call from number xxxxxxxx"); ?

Comment: The cursor returned in that tutorial contains all the information you need, you will have to loop through it as he does and then decide if the call is interesting to you or not :)

Comment: thanks. Could you give me full source code example of that tutorial?

Comment: Thank you very much, sir :) I've tried it, it's works! now i try to learn it. Thanks :) Nice to meet u, sir :)